# FromUri removing parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've got some functionality on my site that if a user logs in at any given point then upon successful login they'll be bounced back to the page that they viewing. And this is all working fine except when there are parameters on the query string. To explain:

A user will be on page:

```
http://localhost:55432/eng/speakers/?altTemplate=Speaker&id=0030X00002QCntgQAD
```

and hit the login button (which takes them to another page), the URL being:

```
http://localhost:55432/login/?redirectUrl=http://localhost:55432/eng/speakers/?altTemplate=Speaker&id=0030X00002QCntgQAD&region=eng
```

As you can see I'm populating a parameter on the QS (redirectUrl)

On the login page there's a simple form that posts username and password to a method:

```
public ActionResult HandleLogin(string username, string password, [FromUri] string redirectUrl)
```

But when this method is being called the value of the redirectUrl parameter is:

```
http://localhost:55432/eng/speakers/?altTemplate=Speaker
```

i.e. everything including the ampersand has been removed.....

Would anyone know why this happens and more importantly how to stop it?

Thanks,
C

Comment: FormUri is used for WebAPI action parameters not for ASP.NET MVC action method parameters. Can you share html of the View?

Comment: probably you can add to Action one more parameter like `string redirectUrlParams` cause it seems this is parsed as params, but you don't expect them in Action

Comment: Ahh it's me isn't it redirectUrl is a single parameter which contains "http://localhost:55432/eng/speakers/?altTemplate=Speaker" what's coming after this is more parameters. so basically i'm being a dingbat